# Can I use Custom labels in VisualFlows?

Tags: flow, customlabel, visual-flows

Whats the best practice in terms of visual Flows Processes in multiple languages? 
 **would appreciate any recommendations..** 
 I find it a bit weird that I need to Clone the whole Flow..
 I'm trying to create a flow with few form pages... some of the input/output need to be shown in few languages since few users (different languages) will use this flow. 
 **no way to use Custom Labels / or using the actual translation on the outputFields on form Pages ??**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Custom Labels are available in Flows.  When you create a Formula, the labels are under "System and Global Variables"

[image: Setup Screen in Flow for Formula]

Comment: Thanks..exactly what I needed..don't know how I missed that..

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

We can use Custom labels in Lightning flow see the below screenshot

**{!$Label.Your_Custom_LabelName}**

[image]